# Lifecycle policy on S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an S3 bucket on which I've configured a Lifecycle policy which says to archive all objects in the bucket after 1 day(s) (since I want to keep the files in there temporarily but if there are no issues then it is fine to archive them and not have to pay for the S3 storage)

*However* I have noticed there are some files in that bucket that were created in February ..

So .. am I right in thinking that if you select 'Archive' as the lifecycle option, that means *"copy-to-glacier-and-then-delete-from-S3"*? In which case this issue of the files left from February would be a fault - since they haven't been?

Only I saw there is another option - 'Archive and then Delete' - but I assume that means *"copy-to-glacier-and-then-delete-from-glacier"* - which I don't want.

Has anyone else had issues with S3 -> Glacier?

Comment: I think you are correct about the distinction between 'Archive' and 'Archive and then Delete'. The latter copies to Glacier, deletes from S3 and will delete the object from Glacier at some specified point in the future. This is how you'd implement 'I want files available in S3 for 60 days, then archived in Glacier for 120 days, and then deleted after that'. As to why you still have objects dated February, unless they do not match the lifecycle policies in place then it might be an S3 lifecycle bug. Might be worth raising a support case and indicating which objects and policies are problems.

Comment: @jarmod Thanks - I thought that was the case regarding those two policies. It looks like it isn't a lifecycle bug looking at Michael's answer, which is good

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you describe sounds normal.  Check the storage class of the objects.

The correct way to understand the S3/Glacier integration is the S3 is the "customer" of Glacier -- not you -- and Glacier is a back-end storage provider for S3.  Your relationship is still with S3 (if you go into Glacier in the console, your stuff isn't visible there, if S3 put it in Glacier).

When S3 archives an object to Glacier, the object is still logically "in" the bucket and is still an S3 object, and visible in the S3 console, but can't be downloaded from S3 because S3 has migrated it to a different backing store.

The difference you should see in the console is that objects will have A "storage class" of `Glacier` instead of the usual `Standard` or `Reduced Redundancy`.  They don't disappear from there.

To access the object later, you ask S3 to initiate a restore from Glacier, which S3 does... but the object is *still* in Glacier at that point, with S3 holding a temporary copy, which it will again purge after some number of days.

Note that your attempt at saving may be a little bit off target if you do not intend to keep these files for 3 months, because any time you delete an object from Glacier, you are billed for the remainder of the three months, if that object has been in Glacier for a shorter time than that.

Comment: Ah ha! I get it now. Thanks - that explains it. I didn't think there would be a fault with Skynet/AWS :)